# How to return the below code in one statement in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I am a newbie to Java 8 and require help. How can I compact the below code so that I can return all of it in one statement?

```
Optional<OfferResponseInfo> offerResponseInfo = newOfferRepository.findByOidAndIsActiveAndIsHidden(oid, true, false)
                .map(OfferMapper.INSTANCE::offerToOfferResponse);

boolean flag = principal.getName().equals(offerResponseInfo.get().getUser().getfName()
        .concat(offerResponseInfo.get().getUser().getlName())) ? true:false;
offerResponseInfo.get().setOfferOwner(flag);

return offerResponseInfo
        .orElseThrow(() -> {
            throw new DataNotFoundException(String.format("No offer found for oid %s", oid));
        });
```

Comment: The `offerResponseInfo.orElseThrow` after performing a `get`, a mere formality, or this is not the actual code? Anyway, mutating the object while accessing the fields of the same object would not be very clean with the functional paradigm.

Comment: I wanted to return the updated offerResponseInfo Object. how can the above code be more compacted with good practice?

Comment: Don’t use expressions like `condition ? true:false`. Just use `condition`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Some code alignment
2. Extract some variables
3. Check if offerResponseInfo exists earlier - when you fetch it from repository

   ```
       OfferResponseInfo offerResponseInfo = newOfferRepository
           .findByOidAndIsActiveAndIsHidden(oid, true, false)
           .map(OfferMapper.INSTANCE::offerToOfferResponse)
           .orElseThrow(() -> {
               throw new DataNotFoundException(String.format("No offer found for oid %s", oid));
           });


       Principal offerUser = offerResponseInfo.getUser();
       String offerUserName = offerUser.getfName().concat(offerUser.getlName());
       boolean isOwner = principal.getName().equals(offerUserName);
       offerResponseInfo.setOfferOwner(isOwner);

       return offerResponseInfo;
   ```

All in single statement

```
        return newOfferRepository
            .findByOidAndIsActiveAndIsHidden(oid, true, false)
            .map(OfferMapper.INSTANCE::offerToOfferResponse)
            .map(ori -> {
                boolean flag = principal.getName().equals(ori.getUser().getfName()
                        .concat(ori.getUser().getlName()));
                ori.setOfferOwner(flag);
                return ori;
            })
            .orElseThrow(() -> {
                return new DataNotFoundException(String.format("No offer found for oid %s", oid));
            });
```

Comment: And mind the possibility to concatenate two strings by just using `+`. Instead of `String.format("No offer found for oid %s", oid)` you can simply use `"No offer found for oid "+oid`, likewise, instead of `offerUser.getfName().concat(offerUser.getlName())`, you can use `offerUser.getfName()+offerUser.getlName()`.

Comment: @Andrew Fomin - How can we make use of supplier here to put it in one return statement?

Comment: @Holger Thank you for the suggestions. How can we make use of supplier here to put it in one return statement?

Comment: @SharmisthaChakraborty you have to make up your mind. Do you want compact the code or do you want a single `return` statement. You can’t have both.

Comment: @Holger - Single return statement please.

Comment: I thought you need to refactor the code to make it more readable and "debugable", this is good practice. Inline all in one statement is awful. Just look

Comment: Another point: `orElseThrow` should *return* the exception not throw it: `.orElseThrow(() -> new DataNotFoundException(String.format("No offer found for oid "+oid)))`

Comment: @Andrew Fomin I agree but my code reviewer want it to be returned in one statement. Since I am new I am still learning and trying to understand. Can it be done?

Comment: @SharmisthaChakraborty I've updated the code in the answer

Comment: @SharmisthaChakraborty This answer did already show how it can be done. Incorporating the other issues, the code simplifies to `return newOfferRepository.findByOidAndIsActiveAndIsHidden(oid, true, false) .map(OfferMapper.INSTANCE::offerToOfferResponse) .map(ori -> { ori.setOfferOwner(principal.getName().equals(ori.getUser().getfName()+ori.getUser().getlName())); return ori; }) .orElseThrow(() -> new DataNotFoundException("No offer found for oid "+oid));` Using local variables instead of repeating expressions still makes it more readable and compact than a single `return` statement.